# How to add some extra parameter in the airbrake parameters for JS errors

Tags: airbrake

When we are sending the airbrake error to the airbrake server, by default it includes the controller name and action name.

But the question is that I want to add some extra parameters like `username`, `email` of the current user. If anyone has any idea please suggest how to do that?

In my layout application.html:

```
- if ['development'].include?(Rails.env)
  = airbrake_javascript_notifier
  = render :partial => 'layouts/airbrake_notifier'
```

and in the partial I have written:

```
   Airbrake.errorDefaults['name'] = "#{current_user.name}";<br/>
   Airbrake.errorDefaults['email'] = "#{current_user.email}";<br/>
   Airbrake.errorDefaults['phone'] = "#{current_user.phone}";<br/>
   Airbrake.errorDefaults['title'] = "#{current_user.title;<br/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a great solution, but the [Airbrake Knowledge Base](http://help.airbrake.io/kb) recommends essentially [patching the airbrake gem source](http://help.airbrake.io/kb/customizations/add-extra-parameters-to-every-error) of the lib/airbrake/notice.rb file.

```
def initialize(args)
  ...
  self.parameters          = args[:parameters] ||
                               action_dispatch_params ||
                               rack_env(:params) ||
                               {'username' => current_user.name}
```

It would certainly be better to have this be configurable without patching source.

What I've done instead is simply add a few pieces of data to the session (current_user.name mainly), since session data is sent with the request.  I wouldn't do this for more than a few little pieces of data.

Comment: Thanks! I got around this limitation in a background job by putting my stuff in the session param: `Airbrake.notify error, session: { car_id: car.id }`

Answer (score 1):

We've just added getting current users into the Airbrake Gem. 
https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake/wiki/Sending-current-user-information

You'll soon be able to sort by current user in an upcoming redesign of the UI.

Comment: This works fine for the Rails side but doesn't seem to capture that information on the JS side.